# Whats the right way to configure multiple TaskHubs for durable functions in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

We have multiple durable functions running in the same app service with the same storage space and are unsure how to properly configure them to use separate TaskHubs.

Originally they were all using the same task hub and we encountered a problem that the orchestration never completed (see  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1748#issuecomment-805945562 for details).

According to a comment https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/904#issuecomment-529052862  we should be using separate taskhubs. So I used the TaskHub parameter of the Durableclient class to specify different ones for each durable function (total of 3).

But now the orchestration is sitting in the instances table with status = 'Pending' forever and the Durable Function diagnostics in the portal is giving me an error 'The scale controller is not monitoring the correct task hub(s)!', but theres no useful information about how to fix it.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?